# Can't get Jenkins to recognise a git repo

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, gradle

Trying to get Jenkins to run with Gradle etc.  Please note that this is a **Windows 10** OS.  Not Linux.

I want to use a git repo on my local machine, under `D:\temp\.git\`.  There is a file `HEAD` there.

On the "Source Code Management" page I enter the following in `Repository URL`:

> file:///D:/temp/.git/

(NB I have played around a lot with the number (and type) of slashes here... nothing works)

The response comes:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c
>   core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///D:/temp/.git/ HEAD" returned
>   status code 128: 
> stdout:
>   stderr: fatal: '/D:/temp/.git/' does not
>   appear to be a git repository
>  fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository. 
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.

I note that it says "from **remote** repository". Just wondering if it might be a question of tweaking something somewhere to specify a local repository... ?

Plus I also then tried running this same command at a DOS prompt without and then with Administrator rights:

> D:\temp>git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///D:/temp/.git/HEAD 
> fatal: Invalid gitfile format:
>   D:/temp/.git/HEAD 
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

... which is puzzling.  "invalid gitfile format" - what's that about? Plus the "access rights" thing: could it be that this is happening due to some nonsense to do with Windows UAC?  But even with Admin rights I get the same message.

*A bit later:*
This command works at the command prompt, including as a non-administrator, if you omit the word "HEAD":

> D:>git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///D:/temp
>   a4ca18f7b218ef57b07f8dceef89ab6bdb5839a6        refs/heads/master
>
> D:>git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///D:/temp/.git
>   a4ca18f7b218ef57b07f8dceef89ab6bdb5839a6        refs/heads/master

Comment: Hold on, hold on. Is the repo the `temp` folder or the `.git` folder? Because every (non-bare) `git` repo contains a `.git` folder, implying that `temp` is really the repo.

Comment: Thanks... tried that! (i.e. file:///D:/temp/)... I get exactly the same error (except it says "fatal: '/D:temp/' does not appear...")

Comment: Based on the message, you might have one too many slashes.

Comment: Thanks again... I tried with "file://" and "file:////"... I've just tried it again with 2 slashes.  Same error.

Comment: Why do you want to *track* a local repository? If you only want to build projects inside that repository/directory, you should configure *Advanced Project Options -> Custom Workspace* to be `D:\temp`. If intention is to trigger a build when there are changes on your *remote*, then this would not work this way and you should consider to trigger it by using Gits post-commit hooks for example.

Comment: @SevenEleven - thanks.  I know very little about Jenkins, and am just learning Gradle.  I'm following a book called Mastering Gradle, and just want to follow along when it gets to the Jenkins chapter.  I have assumed up to now, however, that if I can't configure a git repo in Jenkins I'm not going to get far with it.  I don't really understand what you're recommending but you've give me a useful clue!

Comment: @SevenEleven - hmmm  just had a look, and can't find "Advanced Project Options" anywhere.  This is the latest version, 2.7.2, downloaded yesterday...

Comment: @mikerodent In *General* settings, you have to click *Advanced*-Button.

Comment: Thanks... I have also set Version Control to "None" in order to get rid of the angry red error messages... I take it this is the right thing to do.  Obviously I need to look for a good intro to Jenkins ...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't want to configure a Git repository to *track*. Because you are working locally (only), it would be sufficient to configure *Custom Workspace* to point to your repository (*General -> Advanced*).

This would be `D:\temp`, **not** `D:\temp\.git`, because the `.git` directory is *merely* where Git keeps its information about your repository.